# Lnked server in sql azure db

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, linked-server

I have read many articles but i cannot be confirmed if linked server is supported in SQL Azure DB(PAAS)environment? I read somewhere that it is applicable only in hybrid environments.
Can anyone please confirm if linked server can be used with databases in azure and not just in hybrid?

Answer (score 1):

Linked server are not supported in SQL Azure; you can only create a linked server in an on-premise SQL Server to a SQL Azure database.

reference link : https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1943b51b-151d-4510-9bbd-ceb6b51bde3b/sql-azure-linked-data-base